# Hide copy window background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I adapted the code from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12064/Compress-Zip-files-with-Windows-Shell-API-and-C) to make a program that zips and copies directories. I included a background worker in my code so I can run the zipping routine asynchronously to prevent interface freezing. Here is the code that I have adapted:

```
private void StartZipping()
{
    var zipWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };

    zipWorker.DoWork += ZipWorkerWork;
    zipWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += ZipWorkerCompleted;

    zipWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void ZipWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteLogEntry("Zip Worker Finished");
    var sleep = new Timer();
    sleep.Tick += SleepTick;
    sleep.Interval = DEBUG ? SecondsToMilliseconds(45) : MinutesToMilliseconds(15);
    sleep.Start();
}

private void ZipWorkerWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WriteLogEntry("Zip Worker Started");
    var checkedItems = GetCheckedItems();
    if (checkedItems.Count() <= 0) return;

    foreach (var p in checkedItems)
        ZipFiles(((BackupProgram)p.Tag));
}

private static void ZipFiles(BackupProgram program)
{
    var zipPath = string.Format("{0}{1}.ZIP", TempZipDirectory, program.Name.ToUpper());
    WriteLogEntry(string.Format("Zipping files from '{0}' to '{1}'...", program.Path, zipPath));
    try
    {
        var emptyzip = new byte[] { 80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        if (File.Exists(zipPath)) File.Delete(zipPath);

        var fs = File.Create(zipPath);
        fs.Write(emptyzip, 0, emptyzip.Length);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        //fs = null;

        //Copy a folder and its contents into the newly created zip file
        var sc = new Shell32.ShellClass();
        var srcFlder = sc.NameSpace(program.Path);
        var destFlder = sc.NameSpace(zipPath);
        var items = srcFlder.Items();
        destFlder.CopyHere(items, 20);
        //sc = null;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ZippedPrograms.Add(zipPath);
        WriteLogEntry("Zip Succeeded");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLogEntry(string.Format("Zipping Failed: {0} >> {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message));
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, ex.Message);
    }
}

internal class BackupProgram
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public BackupProgram(string name, string path)
    {
        Name = name;
        Path = path;
    }
}
```

Obviously as it stands now, all the zipping windows show up when this code is hit. I tried to mimic the sample program (which hides the windows), but with only marginal success. The windows were hidden, but the zipping was only partially completed. Here is the modified code to behave nearly identical to the article's:

```
private static void ZipFiles(BackupProgram program)
{
    try
    {
        var zipPath = string.Format("{0}{1}.ZIP", TempZipDirectory, program.Name.ToUpper());

        var i = new ProcessStartInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "zip.exe");
        i.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", program.Path, zipPath);
        //i.CreateNoWindow = false;
        //i.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        i.CreateNoWindow = true;
        i.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        if (File.Exists(zipPath))
        {
            WriteLogEntry(string.Format("'{0}' exists, deleting...",zipPath));
            File.Delete(zipPath);
        }

        var process = Process.Start(i);
        WriteLogEntry(string.Format("Zipping files from '{0}' to '{1}'...", program.Path, zipPath));

        process.WaitForExit();
        ZippedPrograms.Add(zipPath);
        WriteLogEntry("Zip Succeeded");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLogEntry(string.Format("Zipping Failed: {0} >> {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message));
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What I want to know is: Is there some way to use my original adapted code, but hide the progress windows?

Thanks!

### EDIT

Here is the code from the sample solution (available for download from the link at the top of the post) that is zip.exe:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace zip
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Create an empty zip file
            byte[] emptyzip = new byte[] { 80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            FileStream fs = File.Create(args[1]);
            fs.Write(emptyzip, 0, emptyzip.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            fs = null;

            //Copy a folder and its contents into the newly created zip file
            Shell32.ShellClass sc = new Shell32.ShellClass();
            Shell32.Folder SrcFlder = sc.NameSpace(args[0]);
            Shell32.Folder DestFlder = sc.NameSpace(args[1]);
            Shell32.FolderItems items = SrcFlder.Items();
            DestFlder.CopyHere(items, 20);

            //Ziping a file using the Windows Shell API creates another thread where the zipping is executed.
            //This means that it is possible that this console app would end before the zipping thread 
            //starts to execute which would cause the zip to never occur and you will end up with just
            //an empty zip file. So wait a second and give the zipping thread time to get started
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to explain what you mean by "partially" successful at hiding it. Also, is Zip.exe part of your program? Can you edit the code? I'll look into it further with that information. From what u have now, try just using one or the other of:     i.CreateNoWindow = true;
        i.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`

Comment: Like I said in the OP, the windows get hidden when I use the Process.Start(i), but the zipping doesn't complete. When I use my code, one of the test zips ends up being around 70 MB. When I use the Process.Start(i) method, the same zip ends up being around 5 MB and doesn't contain all the files. I'll add the code for the zip.exe, which was part of the sample program you can download from the link at the beginning of my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zip without a window, progress or other UI display and you want to run it in the background, hidden...then why not use a zip library like dotnetzip and just spin off a thread calling the necessary logic to perform your zip operation workflow.

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples

Answer (score 1):

This link provides a good example of something that accomplishes the same thing: http://geraldgibson.net/dnn/Home/CZipFileCompression/tabid/148/Default.aspx

You will have to scroll down the linked page to see the answer.
Hope this helps!